# R get new table

Tags: r, function, multiple-columns, create-table

I have a table with two columns A and B. I want to create a new table with two new columns added: X and Y.

The X column is to contain the values from the A column, but with the division performed. Values from the first row (from column A) divided by the values from the second row in column A and so for all subsequent rows, e.g. the third row divided by the fourth row etc.

The Y column is to contain the values from the B column, but with the division performed. Values from the first row (from column B) divided by the values from the second row in column B and so for all subsequent rows, e.g. the third row divided by the fourth row etc.

So far I used Excel for this. But now I need it in R if possible in the form of a function so that I can reuse this code easily. I haven't done this in R yet, so I am asking for help.

Example data:

```
   structure(list(A = c(2L, 7L, 5L, 11L, 54L, 12L, 34L, 14L, 10L, 
6L), B = c(3L, 5L, 1L, 21L, 67L, 32L, 19L, 24L, 44L, 37L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Sample results:

```
structure(list(A = c(2L, 7L, 5L, 11L, 54L, 12L, 34L, 14L, 10L, 
6L), B = c(3L, 5L, 1L, 21L, 67L, 32L, 19L, 24L, 44L, 37L), X = c("", 
"0,285714286", "", "0,454545455", "", "4,5", "", "2,428571429", 
"", "1,666666667"), Y = c("", "0,6", "", "0,047619048", "", "2,09375", 
"", "0,791666667", "", "1,189189189")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`'s `across` and `lag` (combined with modulo for picking every second row):

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> mutate(across(c(A, B), ~ ifelse(row_number() %% 2 == 0, lag(.) / ., NA), .names = "new_{.col}"))
```

If you want a character vector change `NA` to `""`.

**Output:**

```r
    A  B     new_A      new_B
1   2  3        NA         NA
2   7  5 0.2857143 0.60000000
3   5  1        NA         NA
4  11 21 0.4545455 0.04761905
5  54 67        NA         NA
6  12 32 4.5000000 2.09375000
7  34 19        NA         NA
8  14 24 2.4285714 0.79166667
9  10 44        NA         NA
10  6 37 1.6666667 1.18918919
```

**Function:**

```r
ab_fun <- function(data, vars) { 
  
  data |> 
    mutate(across(c(A, B), ~ ifelse(row_number() %% 2 == 0, lag(.) / ., NA), .names = "new_{.col}"))
  
}

ab_fun(df, c(A,B))
```

*Updated with new data and correct code. + Function*

Comment: Thank you very much. And how can I do it so that there are two new columns with the results like in my example

Comment: Sorry copied the wrong code. Please see update.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72939856/r-adding-columns-and-data/72940104. I am not sure how you and **T_T** are related but your problems are similar and your formulations are the same: *"So far I used Excel for this. But now I need it in R if possible in the form of a function so that I can reuse this code easily. I haven't done this in R yet, so I am asking for help."* :) Let me then know if you need more help after giving it a try.

Comment: T_T sorry I do not know him.

Comment: You can see how I wrote a function in my answer there.

Comment: harre sorry but only your profile is shown, not a specific function

Comment: I've added a function now to this answer as well. Please see this question afterwards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72939856/r-adding-columns-and-data/72940104

Comment: Your data is also the same as **T_T**. If you're not connected in anyway here, you might be taking the same course. In such case beware of plagiarism and make sure you actually do understand the code suggestions.